Run streamlit using domain name instead of IP address
Default setup works
If I start my application as follows:
streamlit run Fed_Net_Liquidity.py

I can access the app here:
http://24.199.124.110:8501/


The issue
If I do the following however:
streamlit run --browser.serverAddress dharmatech.dev Fed_Net_Liquidity.py

And go to:
http://dharmatech.dev:8501/

I get the following:

This is on:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Question
What's a good way to get the streamlit app to be served at:
http://dharmatech.dev:8501/

I currently have apache running on the same server. However, it's running on port 80 and 443, so it seems that shouldn't interfere with this streamlit app on a different port.
Any suggestions welcome!
Update
The issue was related to SSL:
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/hosting-on-digitalocean/69151/1

Domain names have nothing to do with port numbers at all. Domain names are send to DNS Nameservers that send IP address in return, so http://domainName.com:PORT/ doesnt makes any sense.
You can do is Use Proxy Server ( like NGINX) and setup reverse proxy from port 80 or 443 to localhost:8501,
If It is not possible ( like you said port 80, 443 reserved for Apache Use) then create a subdomain like chart.dharmatech.dev and set it's type to service record (SRV) that maps to particular port number. You can find here -> link

The issue was related to SSL: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/hosting-on-digitalocean/69151/1
